# Setting up Sublime Text 3 to use a different build system depending on the folder

Tags: sublime-text-3

I'm currently working on a python project that consists of 2 components. Both of these components are in different source folders.

I set up sublime text to open SublimeRepl and run the current file (with pypy) when I build, which works without any issues.

This is my current build system in the sublime project file:

```
{
    "name":"sublimeRepl",
    "selector":"source.python",
    "target": "run_existing_window_command",
    "id": "repl_pypy_run",
    "file": "config/Python/Main.sublime-menu"
}
```

I would like to set up sublime text to run my file with vanilla python when I'm in the directory of the first sub-project, while still using pypy when I'm in the second subproject.

The projects are too related to use different windows for them.

Is it even possible to do this? I tried to set up variants, but those didn't seem to work.